# bad request in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

i am new to spring and i created simple end point to get and create students.
i have this get mapping method to register new students

```
@PostMapping
    public void registerNewStudent(@RequestBody Student student){
        studentService.addNewStudent(student);
    }
```

and this is my student class

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Student {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(
            name = "student_sequence",
            sequenceName = "student_sequence",
            allocationSize = 1
    )
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
            generator = "student_sequence"
    )
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private LocalDate dob;
    @Transient
    private Integer age;

    public Student() {
    }

    public Student(String name, String email, LocalDate dob) {
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.dob = dob;
    }



        @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", email='" + email + '\'' +
                ", dob=" + dob +
                ", age=" + age +
                '}';
    }
}
```

but when i test it in postman
i get the error 400 for bad request
[image]
any idea please ?

Comment: Please show your Student class

Comment: i updated the post now dear

Comment: Details should be displayed in terminal

Comment: 1) Check the port number if it's running on 1999 port.
2) @RequestMapping annotation is present or not at controller class level which will contain root mapping "api/v1/students" or "api/v1" and then @PostMapping("student")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the URL you are trying to access maps properly.

Annotate dob field with below annotation.

```
@Column(columnDefinition = "DATE")
```

Also update the postman request date with "**1999-03-01**"